# show dialog in rcp 4 eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, windowbuilder

I'm new in the eclipse rcp development. I'd like to create a method that show a dialog windows. I created a a dialog in Application.e4xmi and I'm not able to show that using command with execute method.

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use of the `MDialog` (and `MWizard`) class is not recommended as they are due to be reworked (see bug [460826](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460826)).

Just use a 'traditional' JFace `Dialog` (or one of the derived classes).

Comment: Thank you for help. I used SWT Designer to realize my Dialog. By now I'll use this tool only to realize my dialogs